# Rabbitmq nodes restart in a kube cluster

Tags: kubernetes, rabbitmq, google-kubernetes-engine

I am getting frequent restarts of our rabbitmq nodes, with these crash logs

```
2021-11-12 11:20:00 
stdout
2021-11-12 05:50:00.718352+00:00 [noti] <0.60.0> SIGTERM received - shutting down
2021-11-12 11:19:59 
stdout
2021-11-12 05:49:59.303801+00:00 [warn] <0.2444.6> 
2021-11-12 11:19:59 
stdout
2021-11-12 05:49:59.303801+00:00 [warn] <0.2444.6>      Reason: "Option {verify, verify_peer} and cacertfile/cacerts is missing"
2021-11-12 11:19:59 
stdout
2021-11-12 05:49:59.303801+00:00 [warn] <0.2444.6> Description: "Authenticity is not established by certificate path validation"
2021-11-12 11:19:59 
stdout
2021-11-12 05:49:59.295245+00:00 [warn] <0.1042.0> Peer discovery: node rabbit@rabbitmq-4.rabbitmq-headless.jx-production.svc.cluster.local is unreachable
2021-11-12 11:19:59 
stdout
2021-11-12 05:49:59.295202+00:00 [warn] <0.1042.0> Peer discovery: node rabbit@rabbitmq-3.rabbitmq-headless.jx-production.svc.cluster.local is unreachable
2021-11-12 11:19:59 
stdout
2021-11-12 05:49:59.295135+00:00 [warn] <0.1042.0> Peer discovery: node rabbit@rabbitmq-2.rabbitmq-headless.jx-production.svc.cluster.local is unreachable
2021-11-12 11:19:59 
stdout
2021-11-12 05:49:59.295037+00:00 [warn] <0.1042.0> Peer discovery: node rabbit@rabbitmq-1.rabbitmq-headless.jx-production.svc.cluster.local is unreachable
```

This seems to indicate that the nodes are not able to find each other. The restarts are not time bound, and happen randomly, so not even sure if it's a random issue either.

EDIT:

The chart is https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq

The values passed are:

```
  extraConfiguration: |
      load_definitions = /app/load_definition.json
    extraSecrets:
      load-definition:
        load_definition.json: |
          {
            "users": [
              {
                "name": "admin",
                "password": "dummy",
                "tags": "administrator"
              },
              {
                "name": "management",
                "password": "dummy",
                "tags": "management"
              },
              {
                "name": "production",
                "password": "dummy",
                "tags": ""
              }
            ],
            "vhosts": [
              {
                "name": "v1"
              }
            ],
            "permissions": [
              {
                "user": "production",
                "vhost": "v1",
                "configure": ".*",
                "write": ".*",
                "read": ".*"
              },
              {
                "user": "admin",
                "vhost": "v1",
                "configure": ".*",
                "write": ".*",
                "read": ".*"
              }
            ]
          }
    loadDefinition:
      enabled: true
      existingSecret: load-definition
    metrics:
      enabled: true
    pdb:
      create: true
    podAnnotations:
      sidecar.istio.io/inject: "false"
    prometheus:
      exporter:
        enabled: true
      operator:
        enabled: false
    replicaCount: 5
    resources:
      limits:
        cpu: 2000m
        memory: 2Gi
      requests:
        cpu: 200m
        memory: 160Mi
```

readiness probe:

```
        readinessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -ec
            - rabbitmq-diagnostics -q check_running && rabbitmq-diagnostics -q check_local_alarms
          failureThreshold: 3
          initialDelaySeconds: 10
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 20
```

liveness probe:

```
        livenessProbe:
          exec:
            command:
            - /bin/bash
            - -ec
            - rabbitmq-diagnostics -q ping
          failureThreshold: 6
          initialDelaySeconds: 120
          periodSeconds: 30
          successThreshold: 1
          timeoutSeconds: 20
```

Kube events: https://gist.github.com/heroic/0b18ebd640039191ab120f740569ec4b

Comment: hope your pods resources are fine as i can see `SIGTERM received - shutting down` so there could be chance node killing the POD to request and limit set on POD or so. Check your POD and deployment config and usage.

Comment: Can you give more input on this? The rabbitmq yaml files, `kubectl -n YOUR_NS get events`. I think that what is killing your pod are liveness/readyness probe.

Comment: @Cloudziu Edited the answer to add the charts.

Comment: @HarshManvar tried to find it, but can't see a definite reason behind the logs.